# Apache Spark: cannot improve execution time when increasing number of cores

Tags: shell, apache-spark, time, pyspark

I am new to Spark. I am following this [Apache spark tutorial](https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4297166-realisez-des-calculs-distribues-sur-des-donnees-massives/4308666-prenez-spark-en-main) (in french).

The idea is to call a script called `wordcount.py` (reproduced below) to count the number of words from a large text file.
The authors suggest grabbing the Iliad from the internet and concatenating it a hundred times into a file called `iliad100.txt`:

```
wget http://classics.mit.edu/Homer/iliad.mb.txt
for i in {1..100}; do cat iliad.mb.txt >> iliad100.txt; done
```

When running the script on a local machine using 4 cores (`local[4]`) instead of a single core (`local[1]`), they observe a decrease in execution time of about 30%.
However, regardless of whether I run:

```
time ./spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master local[1] ./wordcount/wordcount.py ./iliad100.txt
```

or

```
time ./spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master local[4] ./wordcount/wordcount.py ./iliad100.txt
```

I get roughly the same "real" time. Worse: sometimes, the time obtained using 4 cores is slightly longer than the time achieved with a single core.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Spark's latest release (3.0.0.) pre-built for Hadoop 2.7 whereas the authors use version 2.3.1.
Running `lscpu` reveals that my computer has 8 CPUs and 4 cores per socket.

---

Here is the script `wordcount.py`:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
word_counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(' ')) \
                   .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
                   .reduceByKey(lambda count1, count2: count1 + count2) \
                   .collect()

for (word, count) in word_counts:
    print(word, count)
```

**EDIT:**

I found that I had to specify the version of Python that I was using to get my program to run.

`PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 ./spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master local[3] ./wordcount.py ./iliad100.txt >output.txt`

Comment: for loop is not parallel i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, this is happening because of the number of partitions created when you load file into Spark.

So, irrespective of the number of cores(in the --master) that you are assigning to your spark job the number of tasks running in parallel will be equal to the number of partitions.

Check your rdd for number of partitions it is creating after loading the file. In both the cases of `local[1]` and `local[4]`.

use `rdd.getNumPartitions()` to see number of partitions.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, Sathiyan! Running `print(lines.getNumPartitions())` revealed that 3 partitions were created upon loading my file to Spark. I saw the "real" time drop from 19s when using `local[1]` to 14s with `local[2]` and to 11s with `local[3]`. I wonder how Spark chooses the default number of partitions, though...

Comment: You are welcome @Sheldon. There many factors to decide on number of partitions. But in local it is equal to the number of cores.

Answer (score 0):

Once we call collect action , the result data will be sent to driver node. Here onwards the mentioned for loop will execute in a single jvm where spark driver is running.